# .Net requirements for Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, bamboo, .net-4.8

I am planning to implement CI pipeline for .Net 4.8 framework application on windows server 2019 box. I would like to know what is the minimum requirement for building .Net framework applications. I would be using Bamboo tool for the CI.

The application is using nuget packages. So I presume following are the commands that I would require for CI

```
1.  MSBuild -t:restore
2.  MsBuild  /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.8
```

AND also  presume we need to have the following on the server

1. .Net framework 4.8 installed
2. MS Build agent.

Have I missed any ?

Answer (score -1):

For the description you provided, you would need the following components:

- [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022), they will include most of what you need to compile applications.
- (Maybe) [.NET Framework 4.8 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks), I can't find if it's already included in the build tools, so I'm listing it anyways
- (Maybe) Nuget, depending on if you're using the new SDK project style or the old one (you tend not to need it with the new SDK style projects)

As for the commands you've provided:

`MsBuild  /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.8` : As long as your project contain the `TargetFramework` node, you should not need   `/p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.8`

I'd add one more switch though : [-m:<core_count>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/building-multiple-projects-in-parallel-with-msbuild?view=vs-2022#-maxcpucount-switch) to enable build parallelization. It might (or not) matter for your solution.

Comment: Wouldn't the .Net framework be enough as it would contain MSBuild agent. Why would you require the Visual Studio Build Tools

Comment: The msbuild packaged with the .net framework does not have all the possible targets bundled. You could try without, but you may encounter a build error you would not see on a dev box

Comment: @Tom Another reason, is that the MSBuild that lives in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` is version 4.0, that's *old*, we're now at version 17.